# How is this property of real numbers proven?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

> Prove that $\dfrac{x^2}{(x − 1)^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{(y − 1)^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{(z − 1)^2} ≥ 1$ for all real numbers $x, y, z$, each different from $1$ and satisfying $xyz = 1$.

How do I prove this?

Comment: real numbers or positive real numbers, which are all $\ne 1$?

Comment: No just all real number, so negative included

Comment: It is little bit tough to prove for every real number

Comment: This was Problem 2 in the IMO 2008. See here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h215222

Comment: If you know calculus, this question is equivalent to asking to prove that the LHS as $f(x,y,z)$ has global minimum $1$ (subject to that constraint) which you could always use lagrange multipliers, but in this particular case its pretty tedious https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Substitute $a=\frac{x}{x-1}, b=\frac{y}{y-1}, c=\frac{z}{z-1}$.

Then we have $x=\frac{a}{a-1}$ and the similar identities so that the condition implies $abc=(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)$ and hence $ab+ac+bc=a+b+c-1$.

We want to prove $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge 1$ which is equivalent to $(a+b+c)^2 - 2(ab+ac+bc)-1 \ge 0$ or, using the condition, $(a+b+c)^2 -2(a+b+c)+1 \ge 0$.

But the LHS is $(a+b+c-1)^2$ which is clearly non-negative. Hence the result.

Comment: this is the same way like in mathlinks

Comment: Nice answer, congrats

Answer (score 4):

Since,$xyz=1$,we have any two of x,y,z is negative or all must be positive and in both case all three are non zero.

CASE 1:
If all x,y,z are positive I hope that  you may easily prove it.

CASE 2:
 if x,y is negative then we have $$x>x-1$$
But $$ x^2≤(x-1)^2.$$since if we assume $x=\frac{1}{2} $ then$x^2=(x-1)^2$
Therefore $$ 0<\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}<1$$

Similarly it follows for y,
But for z we have $$\frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}≤1$$if $z≤\frac{1}{2}$,else z>1
therfore totally we have $$ \frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}+
\frac{y^2}{(x-1)^2}
+
\frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}
≥1 $$
hence proved.

Comment: But can we prove : $$ \frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}+
\frac{y^2}{(x-1)^2}
+
\frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}
≥1 $$.I mean is this result is greater than equal to 1??? If I was right,it is strictly greater than 1.

Comment: You did prove that. You just didn't notice that $x^2 = (x-1)^2$ at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ so it's not strictly less than $1$

Comment: @bthmas thanks for your remark ,I think I miss some thing but I can't able to find it

Comment: @bthmas any way the final result is strictly greater than 1 ,if not explain me how please

Comment: Posting in my phone sucks, so once my roommate wakes up ill post a full solution expanding on your approach if someone else doesn't beat me to it

Comment: But the first two with $x,y$ are strictly less than (since $\frac{1}{2}$ is positive) but the third is greater than or equal

Comment: @SathasivamK: Note that equality occurs e.g. for $(x,y,z)=(-2,-2,\frac{1}{4})$.

Answer (score 3):

it should be $$\frac{(xy+yz+zx-3)^2}{(x-1)^2(y-1)^2(z-1)^2}\geq 0$$
Hint: set $$x=a/b,y=b/c,z=c/a$$ in the given term
after the substituion we obtain
$${\frac {{a}^{2}}{{b}^{2}} \left( {\frac {a}{b}}-1 \right) ^{-2}}+{
\frac {{b}^{2}}{{c}^{2}} \left( {\frac {b}{c}}-1 \right) ^{-2}}+{
\frac {{c}^{2}}{{a}^{2}} \left( {\frac {c}{a}}-1 \right) ^{-2}}-1
$$
factoring all we get 
$${\frac { \left( b{a}^{2}-3\,bca+{c}^{2}a+{b}^{2}c \right) ^{2}}{
 \left( a-b \right) ^{2} \left( b-c \right) ^{2} \left( -c+a \right) ^
{2}}}
\geq 0$$

Comment: thank you for the $$-1$$ in our math circle in leipzig we learned that in the case that $$xyz=1$$ this trick $$x=a/b,y=b/c,z=c/a$$ is useful

Comment: Perhaps you could show how the first line relates to the question. If you take the OP's original question and move the 1 to the LHS then put it all over a common denominator you do not get your expression.

Comment: yes this is true.

Comment: While it is true it is not obvious, hence why I ask can you "show" the relevance.

Comment: i have ad the computation

Comment: it is true, you can try it for yourself